# TypeScript: type or `null`

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have a function that takes in a certain type or `null`. If it is `null`, it should do something with it, otherwise it should return `null` again.

Here is what I've tried:

```
export const maybeMapUserSessionToUserProfile = (
  userSession: UserSession | null,
): UserProfile | null => {
  if (userSession) {
    return mapUserSessionToUserProfile(userSession);
  } else {
    return userSession;
  }
};
```

TypeScript complains in the `else` statement that `userSession` is missing properties from `UserProfile`.

```
Property 'id' is missing in type 'UserSession' but required in type 'UserProfile'.ts(2741)
user-profile-types.ts(10, 3): 'id' is declared here.
```

How can I tell TypeScript `userSession` is `null` here?

And is there a way to have the function know when using it, that if it is called with `null` it returns `null` and otherwise the `UserProfile` type?

---

**EDIT:**

I also tried overloading like this:

```
export function maybeMapUserSessionToUserProfile(
  userSession: UserSession,
): UserProfile;
export function maybeMapUserSessionToUserProfile(userSession: null): null;
export function maybeMapUserSessionToUserProfile(userSession: any): any {
  if (userSession) {
    return mapUserSessionToUserProfile(userSession);
  }
  return userSession;
}
```

which seems to work in code.

Comment: Why not just return `null` explicitly?

Comment: I believe overloading is ok in this case

Comment: Can you add link to [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) with a reproduction? I've attempted a reproduction but am unable to, TypeScript is able to narrow the second return to `null`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdoGULvcAexGQG8BfAWAChrRJZEUNoAFKAmYAGxXOupgBXEAjCFiAWzgAHZlBx5xAFQJy2HbhAAUcKAHN0ALmRwQATwCUxte049S1ZMigQwgqMXIBuapRpUIAA9pAigwZAQidHCpMwAjCABZGTkFfCIVGw17AF5kLUdkQUx5XHSQaxK08WQAH2QQQS4uABpqKzQS9TsUesbm5ByAPgcqJ2AYfOLsMvELUacnFzcPZClZKtmM1S7bTS1p0sUiCx8x5DJkCC5MBcXl92JD6qIzpz8yM6A

Comment: Overloading is one of the cleaner solutions imho

Comment: What is `UserSession` and what is `UserProfile`?  Could you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 2):

Your code [works correctly in the Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwFsoAHAVQGcQYBlEc83VAFRwqoAUYdEsIQAKZJRp0GeAFzwA5GxH1GUgJSSZwzt14gpAbgBQIAB7EcMDPDB5yZogE8ARiACyJWbXl4Ws9Tz7wAvPD8uvDwQlRuYqgqrqIK8AA+8KjIEBAANLrK0l5cPloJSSkQ-gB88ADewfBYiIFhcpGKFVUhcBjIMPhEZMIRjJ5quZqCvbF4inohAL7wIBCUzSGtIO2doaPuqJPwU7pTekA). However, it fails if you [have `strictNullChecks` disabled in `tsconfig`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwFsoAHAVQGcQYBlEc83VAFRwqoAUYdEsIQAKZJRp0GeAFzwA5GxH1GUgJSSZwzt14gpAbgBQIAB7EcMDPDB5yZogE8ARiACyJWbXl4Ws9Tz7wAvPD8uvDwQlRuYqgqrqIK8AA+8KjIEBAANLrK0l5cPloJSSkQ-gB88ADewfBYiIFhcpGKFVUhcBjIMPhEZMIRjJ5quZqCvbF4inohAL7wIBCUzSGtIO2doaPuqJPwU7pTekA). So most likely your problem is due to having `strictNullChecks` disabled. You should enable it (though depending on the code quality of the rest of your project, this may reveal many errors that need fixing).

Another possible problem is if `UserSession` itself is defined as a union of types that includes falsy values. For instance, with `type UserSession = 'UserSession' | undefined;` we [get an error even with `strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgZQnOBLA9gOygXigHJ4lV1scioAfKAVxwBMIAzDHCJgbgCgWAxgBsAhomitGA4JSgBbEWFIo0mXABUsygAqIs7IRAAU9BCoq4AXLDPk1OAJTWSZ3foyGifCAA8wWRGAoAVw4IIUQACMIAFlFZTtKTR09A2hCI14oBltVSmsEvNxaKBx6ISEAGl4nYhT3TxKyioIAPigAbyyoDFYoE1yLR07u7PFgekQ8BSVB+2TXVI9jUzIixz5sgF8oCCEEEeyxiAmpnLWhzagt3i2+IA). So if you have `strictNullChecks` enabled but are still getting this error, investigating the definition of `UserSession` would be my next step. If this is the cause, you might want to [enhance your condition to `userSession !== null` specifically](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgZQnOBLA9gOygXigHJ4lV1scioAfKAVxwBMIAzDHCJgbgCgWAxgBsAhomitGA4JSgBbEWFIo0mXABUsygAqIs7IRAAU9BCoq4AXLDPk1OAJTWSZ3foyGifCAA8wWRGAoAVw4IIUQACMIAFlFZTtKTR09A2hCI14oBltVSmsEvNxaKBx6ISEAGl4nYhT3TxKyioIAPigAbyyoDFYoE1yLPABCfEJmoQdO7uzxYHpEPAUlQftk11SPY1MyIsc+bIBfKAghBGns2Yh5xZzdoYOoQ95DviA), so that only `null` values get past there. You will likely have to add more cases or update `mapUserSessionToUserProfile`, though, so this is probably not really the best solution.

Really, if `UserSession` can take on any non-`null` falsy value, that means something different from `null`, you shouldn’t be using `if (userSession)` in the first place. That is a recipe for obnoxious-to-track bugs.

The solution that will cover **all** cases, though, is to simply `return null;` in the first place. Then it won’t matter what types `userSession` does or doesn’t have after your condition. I think figuring out what’s going wrong here is worthwhile in any event—particularly if you are treating some other falsy value the same as `null` when you shouldn’t be—but `return null;` will probably be clearer to future maintainers.

Finally, you can have the type of the function depend on the type of the input, so if you pass in a `UserSession`, you get a `UserProfile` with no chance of `null` (and if you pass `null` you get `null` with no chance of a magic `UserProfile` appearing). There are two ways to do this, overloads or conditional types.

Your edit to the question shows one potential overloading, though I don’t recommend the use of `any` here. You also fail to handle the `UserSession | null` case, which kind of defeats the point of having this `maybe...` function in the first place. Your overload should be this:

```
export function maybeMapUserSessionToUserProfile(userSession: null): null;
export function maybeMapUserSessionToUserProfile(userSession: UserSession): UserProfile;
export function maybeMapUserSessionToUserProfile(userSession: UserSession | null): UserProfile | null;
export function maybeMapUserSessionToUserProfile(userSession: UserSession | null): UserProfile | null {
  if (userSession) {
    return mapUserSessionToUserProfile(userSession);
  }
  return userSession;
}
```

(the order of the first two overloads don’t matter—assuming `null` isn’t a valid `UserSession` value, anyway—but the order of the rest is important)

Conditional types would instead be

```
export function maybeMapUserSessionToUserProfile<US extends UserSession | null>(
  userSession: US,
): US extends UserSession ? UserProfile : null {
  if (userSession) {
    return mapUserSessionToUserProfile(userSession);
  }
  return userSession;
}
```

This unfortunately [causes errors on **both** return statements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgZQnOBLA9gOygXigHJ4lV1scioAfKAVxwBMIAzDHCJgbgCgWAxgBsAhomitGA4JSgBbEWFIo0mXABUsygAqIs7IRAAU9BCoq4AXLDPk1OAJTWSZ3foyGifCAA8wWRGAoSRxpWQUQACMIAFlFZTtKTR09AwgAHhhkKF9gCGY4GzJVWToceiEhAD4TWxKrWGQnRpyfPIKi83soAH5iFPdPKGtyyqgAb14oKAxWKFrii0cJqemocWB6RDwFJTql5NdUj2NTRfsHPmmAX1WNrbwzrso+W6A), because TS basically refuses to reason about how *values* affect conditional *types*. You could cast both, or, more easily, [use a single operator overload for this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgZQnOBLA9gOygXigHJ4lV1scioAfKAVxwBMIAzDHCJgbgCgWAxgBsAhomitGA4JSgBbEWFIo0mXABUsygAqIs7IRAAU9BCoq4AXLDPk1OAJTWSZ3foyGifCAA8wWRGAoSRxpWQUQACMIAFlFZTtKTR09AwgAHhhkKF9gCGY4GzJVWToceiEhAD4TWxKrWGQnRpyfPIKi83soAH5iFPdPKGtyyqgAb14oKAxWKFrii0cJqemocWB6RDwFJTql5NdUj2NTRfsHPmmAX1WNrbwzrso+W6A):

```
export function maybeMapUserSessionToUserProfile<US extends UserSession | null>(
  userSession: US,
): US extends UserSession ? UserProfile : null;
export function maybeMapUserSessionToUserProfile(
  userSession: UserSession | null,
): UserProfile | null {
  if (userSession) {
    return mapUserSessionToUserProfile(userSession);
  }
  return userSession;
}
```

Overloads have much simpler and easier to read syntax. Conditional types, however, have the advantage of automatically distributing over unions, allowing you to avoid exponential growth in your code as your number of cases increases. This conditionally-typed definition will only ever require the one overload, and for *n* cases in your union, will only ever require *n* − 1 conditions in the return type. Using overloads for this would require *n*! cases, i.e. quadratic growth. In the *n* = 2 case that we have here, it’s not such a big deal—but you can already see we have 1 condition (`US extends UserSession ? UserProfile : null`), but 3 overloads (`null => null`, `UserSession => UserProfile`, `UserSession | null => UserProfile | null`). Effectively, conditional types get us the `UserSession | null` case for free. With larger unions, that is valuable.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript should be able to figure out that it is null there. My guess as to what is going on is that you don't have strict mode enabled.